# How to autoscroll an NSTextView smoothly in a specific time period?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsscroller

How can I autoscroll an NSTextView smoothly in a specific time period (like a teleprompter)?

For example: The time period amounts 4 minutes. The NSTextView should be at the beginning of the the text in minute 0 and at the end in minute 4.